# Is $\{ a-b=y, a \oplus b=x \}$ solvable?

Tags: algorithms

Is the system
$$ a \oplus b = x$$
$$ a-b = y $$
Where $a,b$ are variables and $x,y$ known, and $\oplus$ denotes bitwise xor, solvable?
I've tried to substitute $b=a\oplus x$ in the second equation but it didn't yield anything.
I need this in order to identify 2 lone items in a list with 2 times every other item. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always solvable. For example, if $x$ and $y$ have opposite parities, one odd - the other even, then there cannot be a solution. This is because the LSBs of $a\oplus b$ and $a-b$ are the same (assuming they are all supposed to be natural numbers, if not then it may depend on how you define $\oplus$ with negative integers).

Answer (score 1):

For $x=y=0$, there are solutions $a=b=1$ and $a=b=0$, so there are not unique solutions.

Comment: (Also, as I'm sure vadim already knew, $a = b$ is always a solution when $x = y = 0$.)

Comment: maybe in other cases, where a cannot be b so x,y cannot be 0?

Comment: If x = y = 1, then b = any positive even number, a = b+1 works.